# 4.7 Upgrade issues: invalid value for State on import, country list reverts to US, contact reports produce warning on htmlspecialchars

Tags: wordpress, civireport, upgrade, localisation, 4.7

Upgraded to 4.7 from 4.6.11 today.
Importing contacts containing any value for State field results in an error for that field. Tried abbreviations and full values. Entering that info on a contact manually works OK though. **I have since figured out how to import States, had to constrain the localization settings to the particular country I am importing, then change it over for each country - it's pretty tedious**

Perhaps this has to do with another issue for Country list in localization (Contact Address fields-Selection Values). If I clear this field it populates United States after saving. Would like to include all countries in the list but can't make it stick. For a temporary workaround I have set to a single country (Australia) but that doesn't meet the requirements.

Attempting to run a contact report delivers the following warning message:

*Warning:  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/Common.php on line 144*

there are a couple more lines to the error but they all refer back to the same line in common.php

Comment: To be certain: you did also add the Localization package to the upgrade?

Comment: No I didn't add the localization package. It wasn't needed for the previous two releases. Everything is in English.

Comment: Do I need to add localization package to make all countries available?

Comment: Please try, not sure, would not harm

Comment: I will try once I have setup another installation for testing purposes. By this logic however, US installations would need localization installed if they want to record contacts with addresses outside the US. Odd.

Comment: With the exception of the html header errors, I have basically the same issue as this question here [link](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-can-i-select-all-countries-to-be-available-for-address-fields-in-civicrm-4-7)

Comment: ..and, I have fixed the html header errors by one-time selecting the "View Report" option for Constituent Summary instead of clicking on the report name, now either link works fine without warnings.